# Using PHP to query SQL Server with an input field

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I am just trying to get this query:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Table
WHERE Column1 LIKE 'input' ORDER BY Column3 DESC ;
```

To have this ---> 'input' able to be entered by a user using the input field in the below code:

Basically, I want the user to be able to query the SQL Server using a predefined query but being able to change the 'input'. The query is fine when I run it with 'input' being changed to something I know is in the database but altering the code each time is not ideal.

```
<?php
$dbhost = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = '';
$input = '';


//Database connection

    try
{
$conn = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=SERVER,1111;Database=DBName", "User", "Password");
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(Exception $e)
{
die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );
}

 // This is a prepared statement
   $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Table WHERE Column1 LIKE 'input' ORDER BY Column2 DESC") ; 

    // Execute the query
     $sql->execute() ;

?>


<body>

  <!-- Header -->
  <div align="center">
    <div align="center">

      <!-- Header -->
      <header>

        <div>
          <!-- Logo -->

          <h1><a id="logo">Placeholder Form</a></h1>

          <!-- PHP ACTION & H2 -->

          <div>
            <form action="http://localhost/placeholder.php" method="POST">
              <h2>Select the Column
                <br>plate you wish to placeholder</h2>


             <label id="shift_label">Input Plate:</label>
              <input id="LP_select" type="text" value="" name="input">




    <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->          
     <div>
         <button type="submit" class="Submit">Submit</button>
    </div> 

  </div>
</form>
 <hr>
 <header>

                                                <h2>Please find data below:</h2>
                                                </br>





<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1 Info</th>
            <th>Column 2 Info</th>
            <th>Column 3 Info</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php while( $row = $sql->fetch()) : ?>
        <tr>
            <!--Each table column is echoed in to a td cell-->
            <td><?php echo $row['Column1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Column2']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Column3']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endwhile ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use variable substitution to change SQL statement string like `"SELECT blah FROM whatever WHERE something = '$myvariable'"`; BTW there is no need to use `LIKE` sql operator when you are looking for an exact match.

Comment: @Nemoden surely PHP allows the use of SQL parameters? Modifying the query string is a massive security issue.

Comment: @DaleK there is no security issue if `$myvariable` is properly sanitised beforehand, but I think the OP is not at the level when he needs to know more advanced topics. If I'd go into SQL injections here and escaping, and parameters binding, and data sanitisation, that'd be too much for the OP. I can not teach all the programming stuff in one comment.

Comment: @Nemoden I totally disagree, using parameters is not only safer but should be more straight forward to code. The last thing you want to do is give bad advice because they are a beginner. Ensuring you don't open a security hole in your database needs to be learned first, not as an *advanced* topic.

Comment: And, BTW, it's not the language itself (PHP) which allows to use parametrised SQL queries if you wanna bring this discussion about :)

Comment: @DaleK "advanced" is relative to your own experience. If that's not advanced for you, this is advanced for somebody who doesn't know how to substitute variables.

Comment: @Nemoden advanced is also relative to when knowledge is required, and to be safe its required to parameterise queries. Therefore its basic knowledge not advanced knowledge. No one should be learning or teaching string substitution as a method of passing user data to a database.

Answer (score 0):

PDO makes use of prepared statements, so you'll want to use parameter binding. For example:

```
$input = "Put your user input here";
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Table WHERE Column1 LIKE :input ORDER BY Column2 DESC");
$sql->bindParam(':input', $input);

// Execute the query
 $sql->execute() ;
```

Note the :input inside the actual SQL query - with the bindParam method you can set this up however you want - another example would be:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM User WHERE emailAddress = :email AND name = :firstName");
$email = "test@test.com"
$name = "Sam";
$sql->bindParam(':email', $email);
$sql->bindParam(':firstName', $name);
```

Comment: Did it work for you? If you have any problems getting it to work let us know

Comment: It did buddy thank you  so much. I will definitely use this to better understand how so I can recreate it down the track if needed ^_^

Comment: If this worked for you please make sure to mark it as the accepted answer to better help others in future (and give me that sweet, sweet reputation nectar of course!)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the LIKE then I would add this to tkingston's post:

$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Table WHERE Column1 LIKE Concat('%', :input, '%') ORDER BY Column2 DESC");

Comment: I am just using = now instead and have altered it to have the string defined as $query to be used in bindParam.. I hope that's right haha